# Bootstrap3 - toggle navigation from different graphic

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, responsive

Bootply - http://www.bootply.com/YkWyRzWZDs

I am wondering if it is possible to have a graphic outside of the `<header>` tag control the navigation toggle (instead of the hamburger icon button). This part of the site is only going to be viewed on a mobile device.

I have two rows of image buttons above the collapsed menu, I want one of the image links to act as the navbar toggle. Is this possible?

If it is possible, can anybody help me with the code changes necessary?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to show/hide the navbar using your own icon.

By adding the following jQuery code, assuming that you icon's ID is menu-toggle, this should do the job :

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        $('.navbar').toggle();
});
```

A complete working example is available here : http://ibootstrap.net/Snippets/IDXpmK6/

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need, thank you! The one thing though, is that when it is in collapsed mode it doesn't automatically open the dropdown list of links, it makes the hamburger button icon appear, which you then have to click to access the links. Is there a way that the jQuery code can skip that step and open up the dropdown list? Thanks for this - I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It was simpler than I thought.  All I needed to do was add the code

```
 data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"
```

To the actual image I wanted to control the navbar with, and then remove the `<button>` to hide the hamburger.

I updated http://www.bootply.com/YkWyRzWZDs to show the solution.